# Is there a generalization of Faa di Bruno's formula to compositions of finitely-many functions?

Tags: chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

[Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) is a formalism that generalizes the chain rule of two functions to higher derivatives. I suspect that it is not often taught to undergrads because one can iteratively apply the simpler rules to the same effect, but over time I've find the more complicated generalization useful. While Faà di Bruno's formula gives us an expansion for $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))$, is there an expansion for the more general case of finding
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} [f_1 \circ f_2 \circ \cdots f_{m-1} \circ f_{m}]$$

where

$$\{f_1, f_2, \cdots f_{m-1}, f_{m}\}$$

is a finite collection of $m$ functions?

> Footnote: Assume that these functions have sufficient smoothness.

Comment: Of course, such a generalisation would be "simple" repeated application of the standard FdB; $D^n( f \circ g \circ h) = D^n( f \circ  (g \circ h))$, then apply FdB for $D^k( g \circ  h)$... Notation might be an issue though

Comment: You're right, there is a recursive procedure that would find it if doing it without an expansion formula.